# Как с помощью discord.py отправлять сообщения в чат без команд?

Tags: python, discord.py

Бот может реагировать на сообщения, а как сделать так, чтобы он сам писал с некоторой периодичностью?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import discord
import time
from discord.ext import commands

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True 
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '!', intents=intents)

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = bot.get_channel(ID текстового канала)
    while True:
        time.sleep(10) #### время в секундах, как часто отсылать
        await channel.send("Отправляемое сообщение")

bot.run('сюда укажите token')
```

Проверил, работает исправно. Спрашивайте, если возникнут вопросы.